Incorrect Use of Async Functions in Flutter
So essentially I have a form class in a flutter application. The user could upload a set of images onto the form, and then submit for certain operations to be done to those images. The two functionalities are handled by two async functions, selectImages and mystery. However, the fact that images were "selected" in selectImages (represented by the population of list imageFileList) is not registered in mystery.
Here is the relevant code for the Form Class
class MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    List<XFile>? imageFileList = [];
      

    void mystery() async {

      print("Image list length in mystery " + imageFileList.length.toString());
      for (XFile? image in imageFileList){
         /* perform operations */
      }
    }
    
   /* prompts the user to select multiple images and stores them in imageFileList */
    selectImages() async {
     final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await 
            imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
       if (selectedImages.isNotEmpty) {
          imageFileList.addAll(selectedImages);
       }
      print("Image List Length in SelectImages:" + imageFileList.length.toString());
      setState((){});
    }

    

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("Image:", style: TextStyle(fontWeight : FontWeight.bold,)),
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      selectImages();
                    }, icon : /* icon */
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),

          /*SUBMIT BUTTON*/
          Padding(
            padding: /* padding */,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () { 
                  /*if the SUBMIT button is pressed, performs operations */
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
             
                  print("Image List Length in OnPressed " + imageFileList!.length.toString());
              
                  mystery();
                
                  
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Submit')

            ),
            


          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

and here is the output when I use the form:
Image List Length in SelectImages:2
Image List Length in OnPressed 0
Image list length in mystery 0

As can be seen, the state of imageFileList is only updated within SelectImages, but is not updated elsewhere.
The issue is probably due to the fact that SelectImages is asynchronous; however, I am new to asynchronous functions, and hence I do not know exactly what to do in this situation. Any assistance will be appreciated.

try variable and methods declaration  outside the build method.

Try the below code for image selection and submit after form validation.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class MyFormState extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFormState({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyFormState> createState() => _MyFormStateState();
}

class _MyFormStateState extends State<MyFormState> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  List<XFile>? imageFileList = [];

  void mystery() async {
    print("Image list length in mystery " + imageFileList.length.toString());
    for (XFile? image in imageFileList) {
      /* perform operations */
    }
  }

  /* prompts the user to select multiple images and stores them in imageFileList */
  Future<void> selectImages() async {
    final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
    if (selectedImages.isNotEmpty) {
      imageFileList.addAll(selectedImages);
    }
    print(
        "Image List Length in SelectImages:" + imageFileList.length.toString());
    if(mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Image:",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      selectImages();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          /*SUBMIT BUTTON*/
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                /*if the SUBMIT button is pressed, performs operations */
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  print("Image List Length in OnPressed " +
                      imageFileList!.length.toString());

                  mystery();
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


